# Use of 1=2 in a SQL query

Tags: sql

Someone please explain the meaning of ***'1=2'*** in the below SQL query.

```
SELECT E.EmpID,
       E.EmpName,
       Country = CASE
                   WHEN T.Active = 'N'
                        AND 1 = 2 THEN 'Not Working Anymore'
                   ELSE C.Country_Name
                 END,
       T.Contract_No
FROM   Employees E (nolock)
       INNER JOIN Contract T
         ON T.Contract_No = E.Contract_No
       LEFT JOIN Country C (nolock)
         ON E.Country_ID = C.Country_ID
```

thanks

EDIT:- Corrected the slight mistake existed in the example SQL query given by me.
@ ALL :- The query mentioned here is an example version of a big working query on which I have to reoslve something. I have created a sample scenario of SQL query for the sake of simplicity of question.

Comment: It's always false.  Someone probably added it in for testing and forgot to take it out.

Comment: In this case it just ensures the first part of the `CASE` can never be true so it will always go through to the `else`. Maybe temporary test code that should have been removed or in lieu of commenting out?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: this `1=2` is not in a where clause

Comment: That is really the sql query you are working with?, apart from the `1=2` thing, what is the `Country from Employees = case when..` doing there?

Comment: Has this query been automatically generated by a program?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Nor is the query a `select into ..`

Comment: @Lamak - Corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
when T.Active = 'N' and 1=2 then 'Not Working Anymore'
```

Simple, the above condition will never become `true`.
So the result will always be `C.Country_Name`

Comment: Why not select directly C.Country_Name then? Don't really get it!

Answer (score 21):

There is a good use for this `1=2` part of the `WHERE` clause if you are creating a table from another, but you don't want to copy any rows. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC_TEMP AS
    SELECT * FROM ABC WHERE 1=2;
```

Comment: I've always used `SELECT TOP 0` for getting the table definition. Wonder if there's any different execution plan wise with which method is used.

Comment: Why you select them then??

Answer (score 6):

It is a common trick used in dynamic construction of SQL filter clauses. This allows the automated construction of "T.Active = 'N' and" with no check needed for a following clause, because "1=2" will always be appended.

**Update:**
Whether 1=1 or 1=2 is used depends on whether conjunctive or disjunctive normal form is supposed to be used in building the automated clauses. In this case, there seems to have been a mismatch of design and implementation.

**Update 2**
I believe most developers prefer conjunctive normal form, with major terms joind by AND, but disjunctive normal form is equal in expressive power and size of code.

Comment: usually you do this with 1=1 not with 1=2 .. you use 1=1 in the where clause so that all other filter could go as 'and x=y'

Comment: Oops! That would be true, but the automated construction is supposed to end with "OR" instead of "AND".

Comment: yeap .. exactly .. if there would have been or between them then your supposition would have been true. I just think is for debug reasons. Also because the 1=2 is at the end .. and you usually put it in front so that the statement will follow.

Comment: It could be haven left by mistake by the original author. I can't believe  as this "1=2" being intentioanl by the author.

Answer (score 4):

It corresponds to a FALSE argument.

For example ;

```
select * from TABLE where 1=2
```

returns zero rows.

Comment: Same as `SELECT TOP 0`, huh!!

Answer (score 2):

Use `WHERE 1=2`  if you **don't** want to retrieve any rows,

As `1=2` is always `false`.

Answer (score 1):

adding and 1=2 will cause that case to always return false.  To find out why it's there, ask the person who put it there.

I suspect it was put there so the author could force the first condition to be false and then he forgot to remove it.

Comment: ok.. he might have forgotten to remove it. But what does 1=2 means in actual ??

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that is a debug script. It is there to always return the negative part of the case. Probably on release that part is taken out.

Answer (score 1):

1 = 2 means that we are giving a condition that will always be false; therefore no records will show ('NULL') for your rows...

ie
      Create table empt_tgt
      AS 
      Select empno, ename, job, mgr, sal
      WHERE 1=2;

then assuming that empt_tgt has records for all those columns
when we perform the following statement:
     SELECT * FROM empt_tgt

EMPT_TGT will be null ; meaning we will only see the column name empno, ename, job, mgr,sal no data...

Answer (score 0):

I have found this in several bits of code at my company. In our case it generally gets left in as DEBUG code by mistake. Developers could use it as a place holder which looks like the case in your example.

Answer (score 0):

People use 1=2 to check if their code is syntactically correct without the code performing anything. For example if you have a complicated UPDATE statement and you want to check if the code is correct without updating anything.